# .rds .rdl .rsd in SSRS

Tags: .net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I came across three different extensions while trying to create SSRS Reports.

1> .rds

2> .rsd

3> .rdl

Can anyone please elaborate what are these extensions and what is the difference between these files?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. RDS Data Source
2. RSD Dataset
3. RDL Report definition

Report Definition Shared data source (rds)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-data/create-modify-and-delete-shared-data-sources-ssrs

Report Definition Language (rdl)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/reports/report-definition-language-ssrs

Embedded and Shared Datasets

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-data/embedded-and-shared-datasets-report-builder-and-ssrs